# ¿Es este tipo de pregunta válida? "Ionic obtiene los contactos muy lento"

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, pregunta-específica

Viendo las preguntas vi [Ionic obtiene los contactos muy lento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179660/ionic-obtiene-los-contactos-muy-lento), que se me hizo curiosa porque el usuario comenta esto:

> al obtener los contactos por medio del plugin de cordova-plugin-contacts. Cuando corro el script para obtener al rededor de 300 contactos es muy demorado, dura 8 segundos aprox, alguien conoce una solución?

Es una pregunta que tiene mil posibilidades: el rendimiento de la PC/servidor, la configuracion del script,etc.

Yo comenté:

> muestra el codigo de script.

Porque el autor comenta que tiene 8 segundos de retraso/lento.

Me pregunto: ¿es esta pregunta mala o valida? Yo creo que está mal, pero busco ayuda de un moderador.

Comment: Hola, según [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), esa es una mala pregunta, lo que se debe hacer es reportarla como de baja calidad e indicarle al usuario que haga el recorrido y vea el como preguntar, por otra parte no hace falta que preguntes en meta si una pregunta es valida o no, sino tendrías que hacer lo mismo con todas las malas preguntas del sitio, solo no te alarmes, reportalo y dale un voto negativo si crees que es necesario. Saludos.

Comment: La pregunta era mala y se le recomendó al usuario editarla o, debido a la cantidad de negativos que tenía, borrarla y crear una nueva donde incluyera la configuración/código relevante. El usuario optó por esto último y creó [una nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/179894/250) que está mucho más completa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitivamente esta mal formulada ya que no cumple lo especificado en el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), de hecho esta pregunta fue desafortunadamente cerrada por miembros de la comunidad, puede ser reabierta si el usuario la modifica y agrega información necesaria en su pregunta.

Para que entiendas un poco sobre la razón por la cual fue cerrada la pregunta, te invitaré a realizar el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio, es muy importante esta información para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Hay un mensaje importante de información el cual muchos de nosotros omitimos cuando iniciamos en el sitio:

> Este sitio es para obtener respuestas. **No es un foro de discusión. No
>   es un lugar de conversación.**

Ahora también, es importante acerca de las preguntas:

> Concéntrate en las preguntas sobre un problema real con el que te
>   hayas encontrado. **Incluye los detalles sobre lo que intentaste y lo
>   que estás intentando hacer exactamente.**

Como comentan los usuarios de la comunidad, es importante añadir detalles para determinar una solución. Si se realizan este tipo de preguntas que no están basadas en lo que sugiere el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) en lugar de buenas respuestas, 
se obtienen "respuestas" que en realidad no ayudan a resolver el problema, las cuales contribuyen a bajar la calidad del sitio (las cuales debemos evitar).

Como tu lo comentas, las causas del problema pueden ser diversas, si no incluye información es difícil determinarlo.

> Es una pregunta que tiene mil posibilidades: el rendimiento de la
>   PC/servidor, la configuracion del script,etc.

No debes dudar si la pregunta fue formulada correctamente o no, para esto es importante leer: 
**[¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

**Como usuario del sitio puedes ayudar a los nuevos usuarios del sitio indicando sobre estos recursos, escribiendo en los comentarios simplemente [[tour]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour),  [[ask]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) o  [[answer]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para generar los enlaces, sugiriendo también modificar sus preguntas/respuestas.**